# How to filter out IDs for overlapping date from another table in redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to filter out the bookings of Table 1 which is in between the date range of Table 2.

Table 1:

```
Booking_ID | starts | ends
```

Table 2:

```
ID | holiday_starts | holiday_ends
```

I know there is a overlap function in redshift which can be used but I am not able to figure out how to pass all the date values of table 2 into the overlap function.
I want to do something like

```
select Booking_ID 
from table1 
where (table1.starts, table1.ends) overlaps (select holiday_starts, holiday_ends 
                                             from table2)
```

Comment: How are table1 and table2 related? Does `table2.id` reference `table1.booking_id`?

Comment: They are not related. Table 2 is independent.

Comment: So you want to compare **every** row from table1 with **every** row from table2? What should be returned? All rows from table1 where at least one row in table2 has overlapping dates?

Comment: I want to find all those booking IDs(table 1) where any of the holiday starts and ends is overlapping in table 2.

Comment: Please do not tag questions related to Redshift with Postgres. Although they share some very ancient roots, they are very different. And a Postgres solution might not work with Redshift.

Comment: Noted, its just redshift now.